# Laravel eloquent use id from one table to search junction table?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

So I have 3 tables

-Business
 - id
-Address
 - id
-business_address
 - business_id
 - address_id

And now at the moment when I go into a view business page I pass business->id from business table as $id:

```
public function displayBusiness($id) {
    $business = Business::find($id);
    $address = Address::find($id);
```

Which works absolutely fine at this moment but what if address has a different id?

so:

```
    -Business
     - id = 1
    -Address
     - id = 2
    -business_address
     - business_id = 1
     - address_id = 2
```

So how can I modify that so that when id in business table = 1 it goes into business_address and find matching address id and bring back records that match it

Comment: You could probably utilize a has many through relationship to pivot on the intermediate table and get the address record. see the docs here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you should have is a relationship. So in your `Business` model you'd add the following.

```
public function addresses() {
    return $this->belongsToMany(Address::class, 'business_address', 'address_id', 'business_id');
}
```

Then in your `Address` model you'd have the following.

```
public function addresses() {
    return $this->belongsToMany(Business::class, 'business_address', 'business_id', 'address_id');
}
```

With this, you can now do the following.

```
public function displayBusiness($id) {
    $business = Business::with('addresses')->find($id);
}
```

Then you access addresses by doing `$business->addresses`.

This is all based on what you currently have, so I'm assuming that one `Address` can belong to several `Business`. If this should not be the case, you'll need to refactor your relationship and database, as the pivot table isn't needed.

Comment: I did that and I get: Call to undefined relationship [address] on model [App\Business].

Comment: It's `addresses`, plural.

Comment: i am sure it's plurar in my model

Comment: No I mean you're trying `$model->address` it needs to be `$model->addresses` and `Business::with('addresses')`, you're doing `Business::with('address')`